# Anaconda Jupyter Notebook is suddenly not starting kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to open Jupyter notebook, but everytime I got the message that `the kernel is dead`. I tried `conda update --all`, and after it was done, **I could not even open anaconda**. Then I uninstalled anaconda, and installed anaconda python 3.8 again. Now I get this message:

```
Connection failed: A connection to the notebook server could not be 
established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your 
network connection or notebook server configuration."
```

Yesterday I ran the command `conda update scipy` which was unsuccessful because I wasn't an administrator. Then I tried running as administrator, then ran `conda update --all`. Would that have caused the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**As a last case scenario, if nothing else works, you could format your computer.**

In the future, just make sure to never use `conda` to install anything unless you are running in a virtual environment. If you want to read more about them check this out:

https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/